# Laravel File system(url) public show no image

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

First i run public storage cmd

```
php artisan storage:link
The [/var/www/awendo/public/storage] link already exists.
The links have been created.
```

So now i can upload images

```
 $slug = ($lastInsertId = app('db')->getPdo()->lastInsertId() + 1) . str_replace(" ", "-", $this->name) . '.' . $this->image->extension();
 $this->image->storeAs("public/photos/category/", $slug);
```

It saved but when i try to access it i can't find that thing.

```
@if($imageurl)<!-- for images edit imageurl are $slug in this case -->
<img class="h-full mx-auto" src="{{asset('storage/photos/category/'.$imageurl) }}">
@endif
```

What is exactly i seem to missing.

Photo are there if I check file explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out there a folder in public name storage it is not a shortcut and when

```
php artisan storage:link
```

run it say The [/var/www/awendo/public/storage] link already exists.

so i delete storage folder in public folder and run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Now it is working.